# Debian: Can I remount / read-only in single user mode?

Tags: linux, mount, root-filesystem

I'd like to use fsarchiver in the safest way possible but have no live medium for booting from. I vaguely remember having read something like this though:
Is it possible to remount / readonly when in single user mode?

Comment: Hello. As I know when you're boot your system in single user mode the root filesystem mount in read only mode automatically.

Comment: @svq that depends. For example, consider the recovery mode of Ubuntu. It has two options: start a root shell, or enable networking and start a root shell. The former has / mounted readonly, but the latter tries to mount it rw before doing anything else.

Comment: Ok. Another idea: `mount / -o ro, remount`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one word: yes :)

How to do it is a different question.

Try this in single user mode: `mount -o ro,remount /`

Realize that some programs might not work (vim is the first thing that comes to mind).

Comment: Vim works fine in read-only mode, it just can't create a swap file which facilitates things like recovering edits if the connection gets lost or the process killed. But since it's a read-only filesystem, obviously you're not going to be able to modify any files anyhow so that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Actually in a recent version of Ubuntu it was not that straightforward.
There are a couple of systemd processes which keep the filesystem busy in runlevel S. Which I guess is against some standards...
The solution was to kill them, and remount. In one line, before they have a chance to respawn.

For example the end of output of `ps ax` looks like this:

```
  246 ?        S      0:00 [scsi_eh_2]
  247 ?        I<     0:00 [scsi_tmf_2]
  249 ?        I<     0:00 [cryptd]
  383 ?        I<     0:00 [kdmflush]
  386 ?        I<     0:00 [kcryptd_io/253:]
  387 ?        I<     0:00 [kcryptd/253:0]
  388 ?        S      0:46 [dmcrypt_write/2]
  391 ?        I<     0:00 [kdmflush]
  393 ?        I<     0:00 [kdmflush]
  394 ?        I<     0:00 [kdmflush]
  399 ?        I<     0:00 [kdmflush]
  401 ?        I<     0:00 [kdmflush]
  406 ?        I<     0:00 [kdmflush]
  408 ?        I<     0:00 [kdmflush]
  464 ?        S      0:54 [jbd2/dm-1-8]
  465 ?        I<     0:00 [ext4-rsv-conver]
  513 ?        S<s    0:25 /lib/systemd/systemd-journald
  526 ?        Ss     0:00 /sbin/lvmetad -f
  530 ?        Ss     0:09 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
10406 pts/1    R+     0:00 ps ax
24507 pts/1    Ss+    0:00 bash
```

The processes within `[` and `]` are kernel processes, they do behave, no need to kill them. The processes at the very end, with a teletype are used by the shell you use, so you do not want to kill them.

That leaves processes 513,526 and 530 which are probably make the root busy. So the command line will be:

```
kill -9 513 526 530;mount -o remount,ro /
```

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, stopping services that still showed up in `systemctl status` and killing `dhclient` worked for me. I was afraid bash, with its history file, would also keep a read-write lock and I was wondering how to spawn a read-only shell, but apparently bash closes the history file between commands so `remount,ro` works just fine after closing other processes.

Comment: Just to add that, it is important to run kill and mount together. Otherwise those process may be restarted instantly.